# How to make apt in other distros work like Linux Mint's?

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I've been using primarily Linux Mint for years. I've noticed that somehow `apt` on Linux Mint is special. On every other system, I have to run `sudo apt ...` to get anything done. On Mint however, you can run `apt update` and it'll ask for sudo and then run. If I try that on any other debian-based install, I'll get permission issues about not being able to open a specific lock file. I still want apt to require sudo access, but I'm lazy and don't want to type `sudo`.

I get that it might be a workaround for it to behave this way on another distro, but I'm also curious about what actually makes `apt` on Linux Mint different, too. Is it a fork of Ubuntu's? I know it's a python wrapper around apt-get, does it just run sudo on all the proper subcommands it ends up running? Or is it implemented entirely differently? I'm curious.

Comment: "does it just run sudo on all the proper subcommands it ends up running": https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsystem/blob/78c8277f7990ca9a74d90741bf35efa1e4a9d4c6/usr/local/bin/apt#L148 ``command = ["sudo"] + command``

Comment: "but I'm lazy and don't want to type sudo." Just `alias apt='sudo apt '`?